# ASPxGridView not works in my ASP.NET MVC solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, aspxgridview

I'm using `ASPxGridView` and updating with data from DataTable which, works fine.
But when I'm trying to use edit, update, delete, paging, sorting functions I get in trouble.
The buttons are displayed but the function doesn't work when I click them.

Here is my `Sample.aspx` file:

**[ASPx]**

```
<dx:aspxgridview ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" 
        OnDataBinding="grid_DataBinding" Width="100%" EnableCallBacks="false">        
    
    <Settings ShowTitlePanel="True" />
    <SettingsText Title="Tabla" />
    <SettingsPager PageSize ="10" ShowSeparators="true" PageSizeItemSettings-Items="20" >
        <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" />            
    </SettingsPager>
    
</dx:aspxgridview>
```

The code behind Sample.aspx.cs :

**[C#]**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DataConnector;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;
using DevExpress.Web.Data;

namespace Sample.Views.Actions

{

    public partial class Sample: ViewPage
    {

        private DataTable dt;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                grid.DataBind();

            grid.RowValidating += new ASPxDataValidationEventHandler(grid_RowValidating);

            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                GridViewCommandColumn c = new GridViewCommandColumn();
                grid.Columns.Add(c);                
                c.Caption = "Operations";

                c.EditButton.Visible = true;
                c.UpdateButton.Visible = true;
                c.NewButton.Visible = true;
                c.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
                c.CancelButton.Visible = true;
            }            
        }        

        DataTable BindGrid()
        {
            DataConnection DM = new DataConnection();
            if (DM.login("ADMIN", "PASS"))
            
                dt = DM.getDataSet("SELECT * FROM Table_Name");
                grid.DataSource = dt;
                dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns[0] };       
            
            return dt;
        }

        protected void grid_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Assign the data source in grid_DataBinding
            BindGrid();
        }

        protected void grid_RowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = (int)e.OldValues["id"];
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Find(id);
            dr[0] = e.NewValues[""];
            dr[1] = e.NewValues[""];
            dr[2] = e.NewValues[""];
            dr[3] = e.NewValues[""];
            dr[4] = e.NewValues[""];

            ASPxGridView g = sender as ASPxGridView;
            UpdateData(g);
            g.CancelEdit();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }


        void grid_RowValidating(object sender, ASPxDataValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = (int)e.NewValues["id"];
            if ((!e.OldValues.Contains("id") || ((int)e.OldValues["id"] != id))
                && (dt.Rows.Find(id) != null))
            {
                ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
                e.Errors[grid.Columns["id"]] = String.Format("Column 'Id' is constrained to be unique.  Value '{0}' is already present.", id);
            }
        }


        private void UpdateData(ASPxGridView g)
        {
            g.DataBind();
        }
    }}
```

The Sample is called on the controller page:

**[C#]**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using DataConnector;

namespace Sample.Controllers

{    
public class ActionsController : Controller

    {
        
        public ActionResult Sample()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

The data displayed on the Grid.

I created a new solution where is only the `Sample.aspx` and `Sample.aspx.cs` and I'm using without MVC and the functions are working. The difference is "public partial class Sample: `System.Web.UI.Page` ".
If I try without `System.Web.UI.Page` on my mentioned code it gives me the following error:

```
The view must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewuserControl,or ViewuserControl<TModel>.
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does not the function of the ASPxGridView working?

I'm sorry in advance if it is poorly drafted but not my mother tongue is English, and I am a new programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxGridView is a WebForms control and cannot be used within ASP.NET MVC. Instead you should use the [DevExpress MVC extensions](http://devexpress.com/MVC). Specifically, the [DevExpress MVC GridView extension](http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/DataBinding)

Watch my ["Getting started with DevExpress MVC video"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DshgC2uTxE) to learn more.